# BeautifulSoup returning 'None' object type

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

After watching a video I tried to fetch price for an item from a amazon.de website using BeautifulSoup api.

```
#My CODE 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.amazon.de/Neues-Apple-iPhone-Pro-128-GB/dp/B08L5SNWD2/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=3UH87RWLLO40E&dchild=1&keywords=iphone+12+pro&qid=1605603669&sprefix=Iphone+12%2Caps%2C175&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEzRjAxN0xWNTk0TVpYJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNzE4ODIxMktCWlhJMVlHWDFNMyZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUExMDMwODk2Tk5OVkdZRTJISDVMJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ=='

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
#I tried other parsing methods too: 'html.parser', 'html5lib'. Not helpful
title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
price = soup.find(id='priceblock_ourprice')
print(title) #returns correct string from the URL above
print(price) 
#returns 'None'. Unexpected. Expecting price with some extensions from <span id="priceblock_ourprice"
```

Anyone who finds something wrong in my code would be really helpful for me.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: the element you are trying to find is dynamically generated using javascript. `requests.get` only returns the source HTML (which you can view by adding a `view-source:` before the url in your browser). This source page does not have the element you are looking for

Comment: which element you are mentioning about? Can you explain with more ellaborating a bit?

Comment: go to that url, right click on page, click view source, try finding the element with id `priceblock_ourprice`

Comment: <td class "a-span12" >
<span id="priceblock_ourprice" class=******>
I see this in element

Comment: Are you sure you're checking the source page? not the inspect element page?

Comment: Yes, 
<span id="priceblock_ourprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockBuyingPriceString">1.120,00 €</span>

URL: view-source:https://www.amazon.de/Neues-Apple-iPhone-Pro-128-GB/dp/B08L5SNWD2/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=10Q4K4UTW8BOT&dchild=1&keywords=iphone+12+pro&qid=1605615786&sprefix=iphone+%2Caps%2C469&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExQkkwMjU2ODBMT0RMJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwOTk5ODYwM0pVQUE4OTM1VDBFVyZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUExMDMwODk2Tk5OVkdZRTJISDVMJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can not reproduce the 'None', code works fine, just added `get_text()` to the price and `strip()` both variables, to make the result a little bit cleaner.

```
import requests, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.amazon.de/Neues-Apple-iPhone-Pro-128-GB/dp/B08L5SNWD2/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=3UH87RWLLO40E&dchild=1&keywords=iphone+12+pro&qid=1605603669&sprefix=Iphone+12%2Caps%2C175&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEzRjAxN0xWNTk0TVpYJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNzE4ODIxMktCWlhJMVlHWDFNMyZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUExMDMwODk2Tk5OVkdZRTJISDVMJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ=='

headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
        }

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
#I tried other parsing methods too: 'html.parser', 'html5lib'. Not helpful
title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text().strip()
# to prevent script from crashing when there isn't a price for the product   
try:
    price = soup.find(id='priceblock_ourprice').get_text().strip()
    #convert price to float by slicing 
    convertedPrice = price[:8]
except:
    price = 'not loaded'
    convertedPrice = 'not loaded'


print(title) #returns correct string from the URL above
print(price) 
print(convertedPrice)
```

**Output**

```
Neues Apple iPhone 12 Pro (128 GB) - Graphit
1.120,00 €
1.120,00
```

**But**

As @Chase mentioned, if it is an dynamicly genereated content, you may give Selenium a try, this can handle the load with its [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) - By adding a delay, you can wait until page is loaded, dynamicly generated content to and then grap your information.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I still have the same issue with your solution.
As i said above i am stuck with AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
The variable 'price' doesn't have any value assignined to it. Somehow i didn't understand why the BeautifulSoup api couldn't find the "id=priceblock_ourprice" though i can see that in the source.

Comment: Could temporarly reproduce the behavior that you tried to descripe:

1. Run the code in my jupyterlab and get 'not loaded' as price
2. Running only the price = soup.find(id='priceblock_ourprice').get_text().strip() in an other cell, i got the price information, I also can see it if I print the soup.

Not sure why this happens, but seems to be temporary.